# Updating the running Neo4j Graph Database

Tags: java, neo4j, graph-databases

I am using Neo4j Graph Database for my java project. I am creating .db folder by java program by inputting one .xls file. I am able to update the graph database only when it is shutdown. I am using Neo4j 3.0.7 version. Is it possible to update the  graph database while it is in running state?

Comment: Can you share some more details? How are you making updates? By running a Cypher query? Can you share code?

Comment: I am creating .db folder by inputting a .xls file to a java program. This .db folder can b given as input to Neo4j. But when this  database is running in Neo4j then i am unable to update it. For updation I have to stop the database then only I am able to update it by inputting another .xls file to the java program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have to do is to use the same jar version and Neo4j installed in your system which you are using to open the db folder. Make sure to use the same version of jar and Neo4j installed.